# How can I re-route a web page visitor to another page based on their internet speed?

Tags: c#, php, .net

I have a website to which I would like to bring rich, dynamic content.  However, there's a good chance a large number of the people who visit the site will have dial-up.  Is there an easy way to route users based on their internet speed and give those with broadband the access to the richer, more resource heavy site?

Thanks

Comment: [The first result on Google 'php internet speed'](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/3822-detect-internet-speed-php)

Answer (score 1):

For .NET, there's no built-in way that I've ever run across.

There are solutions that allow you to attempt this in a roundabout way - they look at the IP Address, and do a lookup for the service provider.  For example, a certain IP Range may be owned by MajorCableCompany.NET while another range is owned by PhoneCompanyWithDialUpONly.Com and another set is owned by PhoneCompanyDSLSubscriber.com. In other words, even these services do not pick up the connection speed, they pick up the provider from a known database and make the most likely guess based on the type of service the IP is registered for.

One common solution is to just have a landing page that allows users to choose their experience.  These were more frequently seen back when dial-up was more common, and are not the ideal solution, but based on your budget, it may be a better option than paying for a service or solution to use a hack as described above anyway.

You COULD do something to try to gauge the speed yourself.  I've seen sites that have you upload or download a file and use that to try to determine your speed, but even this is a hack, and depends on so many other factors.  If you think about it, even in a common scenario - a home network - the speed of any individual action depends on whether or not other PCs on the network are competing for bandwidth.

If you really think most of your users will be on dial-up, then you should design for dial-up, and then give them a choice of switching to a more hi-res, flashy version of your site.

Also, one last thought is to bear in mind that more and more users are accessing web sites via mobile devices these days, and one of the tenets of good mobile site design is to design for very little memory and very little bandwidth, in order to serve more users.  Think about those of us with non-smart phones as well.